# Formular una query SQL con campos combinados (para buscar una ID basado en un nombre completo)

Tags: php, mysql

intentare formular esta pregunta lo mas clara posible, resulta que tengo un formulario para la inscripción de usuarios a distintos cursos, y tengo un campo con "autocomplete", para que si el usuario empiece a escribir el nombre, este campo se autocomplete con nombres consultados a una base de datos en mysql,

```html
 <div class="row form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12">
               <input required type="text" name="nombre_usuario" id="nombre_usuario" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del usuario" />  
             </div> 
            </div>
            
  
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#nombre_usuario').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
  
   $.ajax({
    url:"search.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Este apunta a un php llamado "search":

```html
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "capacitaciones");
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT id, nombre, apellido, apellido_materno FROM usuarios WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$request."%'
";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["nombre"].' '.$row["apellido"].' '.$row["apellido_materno"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}     

?>
```

Y este hace la consulta a la tabla "usuarios" de la base de datos con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente, el php me devuelve los campos combinados de nombre, apellido y apellido_materno, para formar el nombre completo del usuario, sin embargo, esto junto con otros datos, debo guardarlo en una tabla de "inscripciones" con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es capturar la ID del usuario en cuestion para despues guardarla en la tabla de inscripciones, el problema es que no se como realizar la consulta SQL necesaria, ya que los campos de nombre, apellido y apellido_materno los tengo combinados en la caja de texto de "nombre_usuario", y necesitaría una consulta tipo "SELECT id from usuarios where nombre+apellido+apellido_materno like "nombre_usuario" "(por obvias razones de sintaxis, no funciona)

¿Que puedo hacer en este caso?,

Disculpen si me falto ser mas claro, favor de indicarme para explicar cualquier cosa,

Saludos y muchas gracias!!

Comment: Quedate con el id de la fila tambien, y asi solucionas tu problema ;)

Comment: $data[] = $row["id"].' '.$row["nombre"].' '.$row["apellido"].' '.$row["apellido_materno"];

Tambien lo había hecho así, pero en el textfield me queda algo como:

172 JUAN SALINAS AEDO

Y solo necesito capturar el "172" incluso en un textflied "hidden"

Comment: no pongas en el mismo campo el id.. ponlo en otro campo, por ejemplo oculto ;)

Comment: Puedes hacer algo así: `SELECT columnaID FROM TuTabla
WHERE (CONCAT(Nombre, AMaterno, APaterno) LIKE '%elDatoRecogido%')` Aunque la lógica no me convence, pues puede haber dos personas distintas que se llamen igual. No es complicado hallar dos `José Pérez Díaz` o cinco `María González` en un mismo sitio. No sé si entiendes lo que digo, filtrar sólo por nombres y apellidos no es para nada garantía de unicidad. **Es mejor capturar el ID de la persona cuando selecciones cuál de las cinco `Marías` es la adecuada.**